# Keyerror in partial update using django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to do partial updates (patches) on my endpoint, but I find `keyerror "profile"`. The creation and update part is ok. But the patch does not.

My Serializer:

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ("user", )


class UserSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(partial=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        user.profile.company = profile["company"]
        user.profile.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        user.profile.company = profile["company"]
        user.profile.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("groups", "user_permissions", )
```

My view:

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User
```

As I said above, the create and update part is ok.

One way I tried was to create a partial_update method in the view, but it didn't work out. Here the example:

```py
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user.profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response("OK")
        return Response("Nop")
```

The serializer is invalid.

Without using this method, when I use the patch (using postman) I get the error:

```
KeyError at /api/v1/user/79/
'profile'
```

#### More info for @ToniSredanović

My patch request:

```
{
 "username": "insomnia77"
}
```

My traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  103.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in partial_update
  84.         return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in update
  70.         self.perform_update(serializer)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in perform_update
  80.         serializer.save()

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  209.             self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)

File "/home/joey/PycharmProjects/backend/frontend_api/v1/serializers/core.py" in update
  45.         profile = validated_data.pop('profile')

Exception Type: KeyError at /interface/v1/user/79/
Exception Value: 'profile'
Request information:
USER: joey

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data
```

Comment: Could you show full traceback and the PATCH request you are sending?

Comment: hey @ToniSredanović thank you. I just updated with more info.